# Can't permanently change instance property from method?

Tags: swift, cocoa

Ok, I'm probably missing something super basic. I have an instance property called `currentValue`, initialized to be a `String`.

```
class ViewController: NSViewController {
    var currentValue = ""

    // ...


    func getNewValue() {
        currentValue = computeNewValue()
        aLabel.stringValue = currentValue
    } 

    func calledLater() {
        println("\(currentValue)")
    }
}
```

When I call `getNewValue()`, the label updates correctly.

But, when I call `calledLater()`, the currentValue is "reset" to an empty string.

At first I thought it was a weak storage thing but Swift apparently defaults to strong storage?

I tested this by initializing `currentValue` to `"a"` and, again, the label updates correctly, but when I get the variable later it returns `"a"`.

I feel like I'm missing something but can't word it in a way that will let me do correct research.

Comment: I think you are not calling the methods on the same instance of your ViewController class.

Comment: Wow, you are totally right. I had unintentionally instantiated another one in Interface Builder.  I knew it was something stupid like that. If you do an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: Your wish is my command. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might be calling the methods on different instances of your 'ViewController' class.

(A typical scenario is when loading controllers from a storyboard; it "looks" like instances in the storyboard, but they are really just blueprints.)